# Disable close-on-click-modal in Element UI

Tags: html, vue.js, element-ui

With (Vue) Element UI I'm trying to disable a Dialog element from closing on click.
In the docs it say there is a close-on-click-modal attribute, but it's default is true and I have no idea on how to set it to false.

`close-on-click-modal="false"` gives this error: `"closeOnClickModal". Expected Boolean, got String.`

Is there a way to disable this setting?

Comment: try this - close-on-click-modal="0"

Comment: @SujitAgarwal That will also give an error: `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "closeOnClickModal". Expected Boolean, got String.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try it by changing `close-on-click-modal="false"` to `:close-on-click-modal="false"`

If you use the double dot, the content of the attribute is evaluated as Javascript. If you don't, it's a string.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I haven't tried that one yet ;)

Comment: I'm happy to help you. Added an explanation..I forgot that first